# How do I display a Custom List form on a page and have the Master Page still displayed? SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, custom-list, custom-form, branding

I created a custom list and will use the a custom new item form as the default view on a new site page.  The problem I run into is that the master page (branding info, banner, etc) does not show up.  I have done this 20 times over and it still  will not display.  The catch is that I created a similar page on a different site collection and the master page shows.  I did use designer to do all of this so I am comfortable using designer and or adding code if necessary. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the form as a webpart on a page, are you viewing the newform.aspx as a page, or are you in the dialog box?

Comment: I added the form as a web part.  I customized the form so it has a different name; however I see the form as a page but the browse, edit, and page tabs are available when it just needs to be the form itself and the page banner etc.

Answer (score 1):

Does using the url below get you closer to what you want?

yoursite/lists/yourlist/newform.aspx

so that it opens as a page instead of a dialog?